# Taking snapshot of the status bar in ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a cocos2d game and I need to take a snapshot of the status bar. I have found that ios7 supports a full screen view capture(including status bar) through the following statement:

```
UIView *screenshotView = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
```

I converted this view to a UIImage and then saved it using "UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum". However, the saved screenshots are all white. How do I fix this?

Comment: Just the status bar? What do you need that for?

Comment: Wanted to grab the status bar and use that to create a better UI.

Comment: ??? You know you can just take a screenshot by holding the power button, then tapping the home button. Or run on the Simulator, use Cmd+Alt+4 to grab a screenshot. And those status bar images are readily available on the Internet too. Plus if you use any elements of the status bar in your own app without at least significantly modifying it then you'd be violating Apple's Copyright.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the apple doc, it says, the method captures the current visual contents of the screen from the render server and uses them to build a new snapshot view and if any onscreen views have not yet been committed to the render server, that portion of the snapshot will have no content. So it could be a issue.

Either you can use if you can

```
UIView *screenshotView = [[self view] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
```

or there is other way, please refer to following docs at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1703/_index.html

Comment: `UIScreen` also has a [similar API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScreen/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:). `Returns a snapshot view based on the current screen contents.`

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, yes it does have snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates method!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
UIView *screenshotView = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
```

Will return a UIReplicateView which cannot be converted into an image. You must use

> drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:

like so ~

```
    - (UIImage *)snapshot:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

its all in apple docs 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html